Embeding google sheets in google sites with google app script
I am currently integrating my values from my google sheet into my google site. I know, this would also be possible by just placing the box of the google sheet into the site but I want to improve the style by using google app script. I got following code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
        function submitForm() {
            const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            const message = document.getElementById('message').value;

            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
                document.getElementById('name').value = '';
                document.getElementById('message').value = '';
                displayMessages(); // Refresh the message list after submission
            }).withFailureHandler(function(error) {
                alert("Error submitting message: " + error.message);
            }).submitMessage(name, message);
        }

        function displayMessages() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(renderMessages).getMessages(); // Calling getMessages
        }

        function renderMessages(data) {
            const dataList = document.getElementById('dataList');
            dataList.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous data

            // Handle null or unexpected data format
            if (!data || !Array.isArray(data) || data.length === 0) {
                const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                listItem.textContent = "No messages available.";
                dataList.appendChild(listItem);
                return;
            }

            // Process each row of data
            data.forEach(function(row) {
                // Ensure the row is an array and has the expected length
                if (Array.isArray(row) && row.length === 3) {
                    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    
                    // Format the timestamp using toLocaleString
                    const formattedDate = new Date(row[0]).toLocaleString(); // Format the date
                    listItem.textContent = `${formattedDate} - ${row[1] || 'Anonymous'}: ${row[2] || 'No message'}`; // Format the message display
                    dataList.appendChild(listItem);
                } else {
                    console.error("Unexpected row format:", row); // Log unexpected row formats
                }
            });
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            displayMessages(); // Load messages when the page is opened
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Message Board</h1>
    <form onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" required>
        <br>
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2>Messages:</h2>
    <ul id="dataList"></ul>
</body>
</html>

and following google app script:
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function submitMessage(name, message) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const timestamp = new Date();
  sheet.appendRow([timestamp, name, message]);
}

function getMessages() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Log the raw data retrieved from the sheet
  Logger.log("Raw data from sheet: " + JSON.stringify(data));

  if (data.length < 1) {
    // If there's no data (only header), return an empty array
    return [];
  }

  // Remove the header row
  data.shift(); 

  // Log the data after removing the header
  Logger.log("Data after removing header: " + JSON.stringify(data));
  Logger.log(data);

  return data;
}

And I think the code.gs works fine as the output corresponds to the values of my google sheet. So my question is, where the error would be regarding the problem, that the site doesnt show the values of the site but the input works absolutely fine.
Kind regards.
I tried to adjust the html several times within the browser console and I found that the error occurs at the forEach as the data is Null but the code.gs returns a list with the correct values.

Kindly share what you're getting on the Google Site. What does the site doesnt show the values of the site but the input works absolutely fine. mean—is it showing up as blank or an error? Also, how are you embedding the Google Sheet into the Google Site, and what's your expected output?

Would you please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

I created a google sheet with the columns timestamp, name and message. When I enter my name and the message on the site, it will be added to the sheet immediately. But the values which are already in the list dont show up.

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example that shows the values which are already in the list dont show up. I tested the script and added data from the published site, the published web app, and the Google Sheet. Everything seems to be working fine, and this is a sample image of it.

@Saddles
Thanks for you patience. I didn't ment to implement a sheet "add-on" on the site. I wanted like in the html script the displayMessage function and the googlescript getMessage function work such that the messages are shown as in the html body with the id "datalist". This is a example: 

The problem is that there where the "no messages" is shown there should be the entries in my list.
